# Producing lossless video from set of .png images using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, compression, lossless

I have a set of .png images that I would like to animate into a movie using ffmpeg on macOS, but when I look at the video produced the quality is always compressed and the resulting video has artifacts when the original image does not. Here is an [image from the video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUpGz.png) as well as the same section of the [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZnL1.png). I have tried encoding using the h.264 codec with crf = 0, but am getting a strange error when I run ffmpeg:

> Codec AVOption crf (Select the quality for constant quality mode) specified for output file #0 (test.mp4) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.

I used the following ffmpeg command to generate this:

`ffmpeg -f image2 -r 10 -i image%05d.png -vcodec h264 -crf 0 -y test.mp4`

One possibility is that it is disabled (see in the full console output below), but that doesn't make sense to me because it does show up when I list the ffmpeg codecs with `ffmpeg -codecs` as

`DEV.LS h264                 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (encoders: h264_videotoolbox )`

Here is the full console input/output:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 10 -i image%05d.png -vcodec h264 -crf 0 -y test.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with clang version 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)
  configuration: --prefix=/Users/user/anaconda3 --cc=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang --disable-doc --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-zlib --enable-pic --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --enable-libfreetype --disable-openssl --disable-gnutls --enable-libvpx --enable-pthreads --enable-libopus --enable-postproc --disable-libx264
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
Input #0, image2, from 'image%05d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:25.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1382x1036 [SAR 2834:2834 DAR 691:518], 10 fps, 10 tbr, 10 tbn, 10 tbc
Codec AVOption crf (Select the quality for constant quality mode) specified for output file #0 (test.mp4) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (h264_videotoolbox))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
GVA info: Successfully connected to the Intel plugin, offline Gen95 
[h264_videotoolbox @ 0x7fc150018600] Color range not set for yuv420p. Using MPEG range.
Output #0, mp4, to 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (h264_videotoolbox) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1382x1036 [SAR 1:1 DAR 691:518], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 10 fps, 10240 tbn, 10 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 h264_videotoolbox
frame=   82 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:07.70 bitrate=   0.0kbits/frame=  196 fps=195 q=-0.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:19.10 bitrate= 109.8kbits/frame=  250 fps=198 q=-0.0 Lsize=     616kB time=00:00:24.90 bitrate= 202.5kbits/s speed=19.7x    
video:614kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.305027%
```

**Solution:**
Apparently it was in fact the `--disable-libx264` tag that was my problem. Apparently its necessary to install ffmpeg from conda-forge rather than the standard anaconda in order to be able to encode x264 video.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're using a generic value for `-vcodec` which in your case selects the encoder named h264_videotoolbox. This encoder does not use `-crf`. Instead, be specific when selecting an encoder and use libx264 (or libx265) instead:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 10 -i image%05d.png -c:v libx264 -crf 0 output.mp4
```

If you want to avoid the RGB to YUV colorspace conversion use libx264rgb:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 10 -i image%05d.png -c:v libx264rgb -crf 0 output.mp4
```

If you just want to make a lossless video of PNG you can keep the images as is:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 10 -i image%05d.png -c:v copy output.mkv
```

Comment: The `ffmpeg -framerate 10 -i image%05d.png -c:v copy output.mkv` produces a video that neither Windows Media Player nor VLC Media Player seem to be able to play.